# How to install WinRM service on Windows 7 if removed from installation image?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have a freshly installed **trimmed-down** version of Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 and I'm trying to get back my CredSSP functionality for PowerShell remoting. I cannot remote to another server from this client machine because the WinRM service is missing locally.

By trimmed-down version of Win 7, I mean that I ran [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) on the vanilla ISO for Win7 Ultimate and removed a great many features, one of which was likely the `WS-Management` package which (I think) contains the `WinRM` service. This was done to save space on the relatively small SSD that I have the system installed on by removing otherwise unneeded features like IE, Media Player, etc.

I am wondering how do I get this `WS-Management` package back installed on my system so that I can do CredSSP authentication with PowerShell? Preferably without reinstalling the system from scratch.

I've tried installing the [Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/7/6/E76850B8-DA6E-4FF5-8CCE-A24FC513FD16/Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu) (WMF 3.0) package but it does not install the WinRM 3.0 service. I have PowerShell 3.0 installed from that package and it works fine, but no hint of WinRM exists on my system. I can't seem to find a standalone package to install WinRM 2.0, if such a thing exists.

Below is the exhaustive list of features that exist on the system (both disabled and enabled), as reported by `DISM /Online /Get-Features`. Note the lack of the `WS-Management` package.

Is there a way, possibly using `DISM` and the original ISO, to add the feature to the current install?

```
WindowsRemoteManagement
OEMHelpCustomization
CorporationHelpCustomization
SimpleTCP
SNMP
WMISnmpProvider
WindowsGadgetPlatform
IIS-WindowsAuthentication
IIS-DigestAuthentication
IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication
IIS-ODBCLogging
NetFx3
WCF-HTTP-Activation
WCF-NonHTTP-Activation
RasRip
MSMQ-Container
MSMQ-Server
MSMQ-Triggers
MSMQ-ADIntegration
MSMQ-HTTP
MSMQ-Multicast
MSMQ-DCOMProxy
ServicesForNFS-ClientOnly
ClientForNFS-Infrastructure
NFS-Administration
SUA
Printing-Foundation-Features
Printing-Foundation-LPRPortMonitor
Printing-Foundation-LPDPrintService
Printing-Foundation-InternetPrinting-Client
FaxServicesClientPackage
ScanManagementConsole
TFTP
MSRDC-Infrastructure
Printing-XPSServices-Features
Indexing-Service-Package
Xps-Foundation-Xps-Viewer
TIFFIFilter
ManagementOdata
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, RTLite kills the files completely, there is no way to get them back. Reinstall Windows 7 with a clean Sp1 DVD.

Comment: Surely there can be a way to extract the package from the original ISO and install it?

Comment: no, this doesn't work as you think

Comment: Well, this certainly does suck then. Alright thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure whether or not you really did remove ws-man, try issuing this command:

```
pkgmgr /iu:"WinRM"
```

Comment: I ran that from a command prompt. It opened a new window, did two runs through a progress bar, reported nothing, and immediately closed itself. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @JamesDunne pkgmgr isn't very UI centric, so yes.  Had WinRM already have been installed, you'd have gotten a "file exists" error.  If pkgmgr couldn't find the package you asked it to install you'd have gotten nothing...  What happens why you try winrm quickconfig now?

Comment: C:\>winrm quickconfig

 WSManFault
  Message = Unable to check the status of the WinRM service.

 Error number:  -2147023836 0x80070424
 The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Comment: @JamesDunne That would indicate you really did remove it from your install.  WinRM installed, but there's no wsman service to connect to.  As magicandre1981 advised, you'll have to reinstall.  I'll leave this answer here as it will work for someone who has wsman but not winrm.